# Is it possible to recieve data only notifications in the system tray?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I send a notification with the following payload from a CloudFunction

```
    const payload: admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
        // notification: {
        //     title: `${translator['messageTitle' as keyof typeof translator]} ${group.displayName}`,
        //     body: `${sender.displayName} ${translator[type as keyof typeof translator]}`,
        //     clickAction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
        // },
        data: {
            title: `${translator['messageTitle' as keyof typeof translator]} ${group.displayName}`,
            body: `${sender.displayName} ${translator[type as keyof typeof translator]}`,
            clickAction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
            senderId: sender.id,
            senderDisplayName: sender.displayName,
            groupId: group.id,
            type: 'groupMessage',
            messageType: type,
            sentAt: new Date().toISOString(),
        }
    }
```

In order for OnBackgroundMessage to work, I needed to remove the notification part from my payload. But that also means they won't show up anymore in my system tray. How can I show them in my system tray? Does it involve making a notification channel?

I added Application.kt

```
package HERE_I_HAVE_MY_PACKAGE_NAME

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService

public class Application: FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {
  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
  }

  override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {
    FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry)
  }
}
```

And FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.kt

```
package HERE_I_HAVE_MY_PACKAGE_NAME

import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin

class FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant {
  companion object {
    fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {
      if (alreadyRegisteredWith(registry)) {
        return;
      }
      FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"))
    }

    fun alreadyRegisteredWith(registry: PluginRegistry): Boolean {
      val key = FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant::class.java.name
      if (registry.hasPlugin(key)) {
        return true
      }
      registry.registrarFor(key)
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company_name.app_name">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="App Name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>  
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up sending 2 notifications which works. 1 with a notification and data object and the other with just the data object. In my front-end I check if it is a data only notification or not.

Answer (score 2):

I use the `flutter_local_notifications` plugin together with FCM, once you have the background message handler, Handle the data and call a function that shows a notification and the plugin will create a notification for you.

An example:

This should be in some sort of helper class:

```
  static Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    if (message.containsKey('data')) {
      final body = message['data']['message'];
      final title = message['data']['title'];
      final notifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
      showOngoingNotification(notifications,title, body);
    }
  }

  static NotificationDetails get _dets {
    final androidChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel id',
      'channel name',
      'channel description',
      importance: Importance.Max,
      priority: Priority.High,
      ongoing: false,
      autoCancel: true,
    );
    final iOSChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    return NotificationDetails(androidChannelSpecifics, iOSChannelSpecifics);
  }

  static Future showOngoingNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPluginnotifications,String title, String body) async 
    var id = 0;
    var payload = 'somepayload';
    NotificationDetails dets = _dets;
    notifications.show(id, title, body, dets, payload: payload)
  }
```

This is in main.dart:

```
final notifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  void InitializeLocalNotifs(){
    final settingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon'); //make sure this is the same name as your icon
    final settingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (id, title, body, payload) =>
            onSelectNotification(payload)); //if you want to get permissions at a different time set everything to false and ask for them later

    notifications.initialize(
        InitializationSettings(settingsAndroid, settingsIOS),
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
  }

 Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    //do whatever with payload, I usually send the page to push in the payload and push it like this
   // await Navigator.pushNamed(context, payload);
  }

 @override
  void initState() {
    InitializeLocalNotifs();
    InitializeFCM();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Does it also work on IOS? I read that the onBackgroundMessage doesn't work on IOS.

Comment: I haven't tested it but IOS should catch the `onLaunch` and `onResume` callbacks in the `fcm.configure` setup, you could call show notification from there and it would work the same

Comment: But I want the notification to show when the app is closed. Rhe onResume and onLaunch are only triggerd if you click on the notification.

Comment: Yea looks like you're right, Best bet seems to be a native code implementation

Comment: Could you maybe upvote the question? I would love to get some attention for this.